# Run searchd without any index

Tags: sphinx

I want to run searchd deamon without any index defined.
My indexes are added dynamicly, when indexer is called with --rotate option.

When I provide config without any index i receive this output:

```
Sphinx 2.2.10-id64-release (2c212e0)  Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff 
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc ( http://sphinxsearch.com)
using config file 'var/sphinx.conf.in'... FATAL: no indexes found in 'var/sphinx.conf.in'
```

My sphinx.conf file is just:

```
searchd
{
          log = sphinxsearchd.log
          binlog_path = .
          read_timeout = 5
          pid_file = searchd.pid
}
```

Is there any way to achieve running searchd with empty index list?